# How to avoid duplicate rows using joined tables with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have this query and I'm getting twice the same row but I want to get just with one row with the different values

```
SELECT * FROM comprobante C 
INNER JOIN emisor E
INNER JOIN conceptos CO 
ON C.id = E.idXML
AND C.id = CO.idXML
WHERE C.tipoComprobante = 'I' AND E.rfc = 'HECR610204JC7'
AND DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31'
```

this query display this data:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
              id: 3
           folio:
           serie:
           total: 12950.00
        subtotal: 12950.00
 lugarExpedicion: 60080
 tipoComprobante: I
          moneda: MXN
      metodoPago:
       formaPago:
           fecha: 2020-04-03 13:38:00
         version: 3.3
              id: 3
           idXML: 3
             rfc: HECR610204JC7
          nombre: RAMON EDUARDO HERNANDEZ CADENA
         regimen:
            pais:
          estado:
    codigoPostal: 0
       municipio:
       localidad:
         colonia:
       numeroExt:
       numeroInt:
           calle:
   regimenFiscal: 612
              id: 5
           idXML: 3
   claveProdServ: 85122000
noIdentificacion:
        cantidad: 70.00
     claveUnidad: E48
     descripcion: VALORACION MEDICA XX
   valorUnitario: 185.00
         importe: 12950.00
*************************** 2. row ***************************
              id: 3
           folio:
           serie:
           total: 12950.00
        subtotal: 12950.00
 lugarExpedicion: 60080
 tipoComprobante: I
          moneda: MXN
      metodoPago:
       formaPago:
           fecha: 2020-04-03 13:38:00
         version: 3.3
              id: 3
           idXML: 3
             rfc: HECR610204JC7
          nombre: RAMON EDUARDO HERNANDEZ CADENA
         regimen:
            pais:
          estado:
    codigoPostal: 0
       municipio:
       localidad:
         colonia:
       numeroExt:
       numeroInt:
           calle:
   regimenFiscal: 612
              id: 6
           idXML: 3
   claveProdServ: 85122000
noIdentificacion:
        cantidad: 70.00
     claveUnidad: E48
     descripcion: VALORACION MEDICA YY
   valorUnitario: 185.00
         importe: 12950.00
```

As you can see the data is the same the only different values are in `descripcion` I want to get those two values in just one column in one row, is this possible? what should do I need to do?

I have 3 tables, `comprobante, emisor, conceptos` but `conceptos` could have many records belonging to `comprobante` and comprobante is one to many relantionship, I hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT C.id, GROUP_CONCAT(CO.descripcion)
FROM comprobante C 
INNER JOIN emisor E
ON
C.id = E.idXML
INNER JOIN conceptos CO 
ON 
C.id = CO.idXML
WHERE C.tipoComprobante = 'I' AND E.rfc = 'HECR610204JC7'
AND DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-31'
GROUP BY C.id
```

If you add on the select and the group by the other fields you should get what you need. `GROUP_CONCAT(CO.descripcion)` is like a "sum" when grouping that concatenate strings.
I moved the join conditions, the first join was actually a cartesian product in your version

Comment: thanks @nbk for the code block, was struggling on mobile